# Conversion from "string" to Type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vba

I have been having this problem lately with the code i'm making for a school encryption program, and I have been trying for hours to get around this error but I cant seem to get it working, What do you's thing?

```
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim charPos As Integer = 0
    Dim Cipher As String = ""
    Dim x As Boolean
    Dim Random As Boolean

    If input = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter your text for encryption including only characters A-Z")
    End If

    Select Case Random
        Case 0
            Random = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Case 1
            Random = "selection1"
            x = True
        Case Else
            x = False
    End Select

    If x = True Then
        Dim alphabet As String = "abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        Dim code As String = "kxgtlmpqbwcnderfahjusvi yoz"

        For i = 0 To input.Length - 1

            Try
                charPos = alphabet.IndexOf(input(i))
                Cipher = Cipher & code(charPos)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Please enter your text for encryption including only characters A-Z")
            End Try
        Next i
        TextBox1.Text = (Cipher)
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

The actual error itself in Visual Basic is at

```
Random = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Sorry if this is hard to understand, I'm new to both Stackoverflow, and VB so if you don't quite understand it comment please :)

Comment: What is the error displayed by that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using your code.

```
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim charPos As Integer = 0
    Dim Cipher As String = ""

    If input = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter your text for encryption including only characters A-Z")
    End If

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Dim alphabet As String = "abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        Dim code As String = "kxgtlmpqbwcnderfahjusvi yoz"

        For i = 0 To input.Length - 1

            Try
                charPos = alphabet.IndexOf(input(i))
                Cipher = Cipher & code(charPos)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Please enter your text for encryption including only characters A-Z")
            End Try
        Next i
        TextBox1.Text = (Cipher)
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```